# Mysql add trigger after insert blank value convert to null

Tags: mysql, triggers

After insert in `table_user`, I want the filed `user_notification` and `user_recover` are null. In this moment, this filed are blank and not null because the form send POST data same blank value.

How to create this trigger?

Comment: I think you mean: "After inserting a record in TABLE USER, I want the FIELDS user_notification and user_recover to be set to null values. At the moment, these 2 fields are set to empty strings (ie. blank, not null) because of the from sending empty strings"

Comment: A trigger is not really the correct way to solve this problem - that trigger will fire EVERY time that a record is saved or updated, affecting database performance (in a bad way!). Change the form so it does NOT pass empty strings OR remove them before saving to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution:

```
    delimiter $$
create trigger nullify_blanks_ins before insert on your_table
for each row begin
    if new.string = '' then
        set new.string = null;
    end if;
end;
$$
create trigger nullify_blanks_upd before update on your_table
for each row begin
    if new.string = '' then
        set new.string = null;
    end if;
end;
$$  
delimiter ;
```

Ref: [Is there a way in MySQL to automatically convert empty string to NULL value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042559/is-there-a-way-in-mysql-to-automatically-convert-empty-string-to-null-value)

Thanks for previous Answers.